# Spark session does not exist in the jvm

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a problem with running multiple processes connecting to the same Azure databricks platform. Everything works perfectly when I have only one process running but any additional one causes that new additional process to process being killed with the error `Spark session does not exist in the jvm`.

That's how I initialize SparkSession:

```
SparkSession.builder
            .master("local")
            .appName("name")
            .getOPrCreate()
```

It is possible that there can be only one SparkSession on the cluster and that is why the second process is killed during SparkSession init?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: remove `.master("local")`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. I have got that kind of error `py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server (127.0.0.1:45085)`